# Focus keybinging on the "Type to search in keybindings" on the keybings shortcuts file in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

Is there a keybing to focus on the "Type to search in keybindings" on the keybings shortcuts file in VS Code? If not, is there a way to set it? I just don't want to use the mouse when I want to search for another keybinding...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Control-f` (or `Command-F` on Mac) brings me there